# Redirect from falcon authenticate

Tags: redirect, falconframework

In my falcon app I want to redirect to another page from the authenticate function.

I am doing this:

```
resp.status = falcon.HTTP_301
resp.set_header('Location', '/http://foo.bar.com:8004/falcon_passthrough/')
```

But it still calls the underlying endpoint on return and does not redirect.

Is there a way to cause this redirect and not call the underlying endpoint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `1.0.0rc1` just do:

```
raise falcon.HTTPMovedPermanently(location)
```

Comment: Thanks. I found that method after I posted this question. We were running 0.2.0. I upgraded to 1.0.0, but our app doesn't seem to work with that. Trying to track down that problem now.

Comment: Hum, check if you don't have a custom `error_handler` registered that might catching that HTTP exception (and therefore not handled by falcon)

Comment: The server won't even start up with 1.0.0. It's getting `app = falcon.API(before=[authenticate], after=[crossdomain])
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'after'` Guess something changed in 1.0.0.

Comment: AFAIK, `before` and `after` are not accepted arguments for `falcon.API()`. Maybe you're trying to use middlewares ?  `falcon.API(middleware=[])`

Comment: This is an app that was just dropped in my lap, and I have no previous experience with falcon. That code worked in 0.3.0. We want to call authenticate before each request and crossdomain after each request. How would we do that in 1.0.0?

Comment: You should be able to accomplish that with middleware. Check out quickstart guide: https://github.com/falconry/falcon/blob/master/doc/user/quickstart.rst

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112314/discussion-between-joarleymoraes-and-larry-martell).