# Redirect request to different Resource(Falcon)

Tags: python-3.x, falconframework

I am using Python3.4 and Falcon1.0 . I want to redirect request to another resource in falcon API.

For example, I have 2 resources:

```
class Res1(object):
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        print("I'm on resource 1")
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200

class Res2(object):
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        print("I'm on resource 2")
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
```

And API URL format is `localhost/{id}`. I want to call `Res1` if `id` is 1 else `Res2`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect from falcon authenticate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300822/redirect-from-falcon-authenticate)

Answer (score 0):

```
exception falcon.HTTPMovedPermanently(location)
```

you can try this or explain more

Comment: raise falcon.HTTPMovedPermanently('https://google.com') working in 2.x

Answer (score 0):

You should better put your logic in python function and call that function based on if else condition in any of your API, a reusable and loosely coupled approach.