# How to do an internal redirect in python falcon

Tags: falconframework

How can I make an "internal redirect" in Falcon?

I setup static routes with:

```
app.add_static_route('/', os.path.abspath(here + '/static/')
```

And I want to redirect '*/*' to '*/index.html*', but not as an http 3xx, I want to do it internally, so that the path as far as the browser is concerned is still '*/*' but the content is what is the content of '*/static/index.html*'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect from falcon authenticate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300822/redirect-from-falcon-authenticate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Falcon 1.4.1 there is no way to do "internal redirection" not to reply with a single file, but I was able to implement this using a sink and regex:

```
import os
import falcon

WORKING_DIRECTORY = os.getcwd()
STATIC = 'static/'

def apex(req, resp):
    resp.content_type = 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
    filename = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(WORKING_DIRECTORY, STATIC, 'index.html'))
    with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
        resp.body = f.read()

app.add_sink(apex, prefix='^/$')
app.add_static_route('/', os.path.abspath(os.path.join(WORKING_DIRECTORY, STATIC)))
```